# How to enable night mode programmatically?

Tags: android, android-dark-theme, android-night-mode, android-darkmode

I am looking for a way to enable night mode programmatically with an Android code:

```java
public static void setNightMode(Context target, boolean state){

    UiModeManager uiManager = (UiModeManager) target.getSystemService(Context.UI_MODE_SERVICE);

    if (state) {
        //uiManager.enableCarMode(0);
        uiManager.setNightMode(UiModeManager.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
    } else {
        // uiManager.disableCarMode(0);
        uiManager.setNightMode(UiModeManager.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
    }
}
```

Nothing has changed on my screen, the night mode is still disables.
According to this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/UiModeManager.html#MODE_NIGHT_YES)

There is no need to enable carMode or deskMode.
I have the following logcat on Android Studio:

```
11-26 12:15:16.662 3823-3823/? D/UiModeManager: updateConfigurationLocked: mDockState=0; mCarMode=false; mNightMode=2; uiMode=33
11-26 12:15:26.802 3823-3823/? V/UiModeManager: updateLocked: null action, mDockState=0, category=null
```

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31934503/to-implement-android-night-mode-using-uimodemanager-and-enable-car-mode-but-sh

Comment: I want to change night mode everywhere ,not in my app.I don't need to switch some themes.

Comment: Did you check this note? "Note: On API 22 and below, changes to the night mode are only effective when the car or desk mode is enabled on a device. Starting in API 23, changes to night mode are always effective."

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? I am struggling with setNightMode and I am not able to get it on Android 10 or 11

Answer (score 93, accepted):

**SIMPLEST SOLUTION**

You can enable/disable application's dark theme just by:

1. enable dark theme:

   ```
    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
   ```
2. forcefully disable dark theme:

   ```
    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
   ```
3. set app theme based on mobile settings of dark mode, i.e. if dark mode is enabled then the theme will be set to a dark theme, if not then
   the default theme, but this will only work in **version >= Android version Q (10)**

   ```
    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM)
   ```

**Notes:**

1. Your base theme for app/activity should be

> "Theme.AppCompat.DayNight"

like

```
<style name="DarkTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

2. Your res folder's names would end with -night so that different colors and images you can set for day and night themes like

drawable & drawable-night,
values & values-night

Comment: Unless I am wrong, I believe OP was looking for a way to change night mode device-wise. Your code works perfectly fine app-wise. As I was looking for a way to change for the whole device, `UiManager` seems the right class to do so.

Comment: Works perfectly for me!

Comment: Works perfectly for me, too!

Comment: this is not working for me, are there any additional clues as to how to correctly implement this?

Answer (score 18):

Make sure to change the default theme from `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` to `Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar` in the *styles.xml* file and then do `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)` to switch to the night mode. I have tested it in APIv23(Android 6.0) and above and it is working fine.
For a better explanation see [this codelab by Android](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-training-drawables-styles-and-themes/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Fandroid-training#5)

Comment: Hello Neeraj Sewani. I am trying to set an app that simply toggles the value of Night mode in the whole device. I am using uiManager.setNightMode(UiModeManager.MODE_NIGHT_YES) or MODE_NIGHT_NO. But I am not able to get it. Do I also have to change the "default theme" in my app? I don't mind how my app is displayed. I just want to change the device Night mode. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

This code is working perfectly for me, though you may just need to restart your app. But keep in mind, that this code **enables the Dark Mode system-wide**, not just in the app:

```
public static void setNightMode(Context target , boolean state){

    UiModeManager uiManager = (UiModeManager) target.getSystemService(Context.UI_MODE_SERVICE);

    if (VERSION.SDK_INT <= 22) {
        uiManager.enableCarMode(0);
    }
    
    if (state) {
        uiManager.setNightMode(UiModeManager.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
    } else {
        uiManager.setNightMode(UiModeManager.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
    }
}
```

This worked for me in Kitkat.

Answer (score 3):

Remember that `Dark Mode` is not `Night Mode`. They are completely different. DM was introduce in Android 10 that enforce built-in black and white color while NM was release in earlier version that uses either default/custom style commonly called as **Resource Qualifiers**. If you want to handle your own custom light/night style and not relying on Android's built-in dark style, you may want to set `forceDarkAllowed` to `false` in themes.xml or style.xml to avoid conflict.

To change your app mode to night you can do something like this

Application class onCreate

```
   val isAppNight = sharedPref.prefInt(DAY_NIGHT_THEME)

    // This will be the top level handling of theme
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
        // If you don't want to adapt the device's theme settings, uncomment the snippet below
        /*uiModeManager.setApplicationNightMode(
            when (isAppNight) {
                DAY_THEME -> UiModeManager.MODE_NIGHT_NO // User set this explicitly
                NIGHT_THEME -> UiModeManager.MODE_NIGHT_YES // User set this explicitly
                else -> UiModeManager.MODE_NIGHT_AUTO // Follow the device Dark Theme settings when not define yet by user
            }
        )*/
    } else {

        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(
            when (isAppNight) {
                DAY_THEME -> AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO // User set this explicitly
                NIGHT_THEME -> AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES // User set this explicitly
                else -> AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM // For Android 10 and 11, follow the device Dark Theme settings when not define yet by user
            }
        )

    }
```

Switch component

```
   // Update Light/Night mode status
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
       uiModeManager.setApplicationNightMode(
           when (item.isChecked) {
               true -> UiModeManager.MODE_NIGHT_YES
               else -> UiModeManager.MODE_NIGHT_NO
           }
        )
   } else {
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(
            when (item.isChecked) {
                true -> AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES
                else -> AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO
             }
         )
   }

   // Save settings configuration in SharedPreferences
   sharedPref.prefInt(
       DAY_NIGHT_THEME,
       if (item.isChecked)
           NIGHT_THEME
       else
           DAY_THEME
   )
```

Here we are using `SharedPreference` for storing and updating the preferred theme of user. You may also need to use `Theme.Material3.DayNight` as your parent theme.

Comment: thanks. now i can develop dark theme on android during the day (noon).

Answer (score 1):

One more thing: your Activity needs to extend from AppCompatActivity.

If it extends the plain Activity, then calling  AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode will not work.

Answer (score 1):

```
int nightModeFlags =
getContext().getResources().getConfiguration().uiMode &
Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK;
switch (nightModeFlags) {
case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES:
     doStuff();
     break;

case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO:
     doStuff();
     break;

case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_UNDEFINED:
     doStuff();
     break;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

[NightOwl](https://github.com/ashqal/NightOwl) has its own implementation for switching day/night mode on Android. Getting started with NightOwl is super easy. Here's a code snippet:

Init the NightOwl in Application class,

```
NightOwl.builder().defaultMode(0).create();
```

Call three method in your Activity class,

```
public class DemoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // step1 before super.onCreate
        NightOwl.owlBeforeCreate(this);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_demo);

        // step2 after setContentView
        NightOwl.owlAfterCreate(this);

        // write your code
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // step3 onResume
        NightOwl.owlResume(this);
    }

}
```

Switch skin everywhere as you like,

```
View v = findViewById(R.id.button);
v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        NightOwl.owlNewDress(SettingActivity.this);
    }
});
```

Comment: Google libraries will be the best choice