# Programmatically enable/disable Night Light in Android Application

Tags: android

I am currently working on a CMS based Android Application to allow school students to study and prepare for their exams using their android devices. However prolonged exposure to blue light can have an adverse effect on their eyes. Is there a way to programatically enable night light while the application is being used in the android device and return to normal settings when the application is closed?

Comment: Your question is not well organized, Like why you want to turn it off while the application is not in use?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable night mode programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47495534/how-to-enable-night-mode-programmatically)

Comment: I need the night light feature, not the night mode. My app is using android webview at certain places that makes night mode rendered useless for me ..

Comment: Whoever marked the question as duplicate did 100% wrong, but to be honest this use case seems also completely misplaced. Whether the user takes relief from the warmer gamma doesn't depend on the kind of application. If they want it, they'll have already enabled it (maybe if really really any, you might want to opt-out for very selected kinds of "colour delicate" tasks but this isn't it). Unless you want to reinvent yourself the wheel of color management for older phones, my suggestion would be just at most to start the `com.android.settings.display.NightDisplaySettings` fragment/panel.

Answer (score 0):

**1st Option**
You can use material theme to do this.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
```

if you want your app to follow system settings to can go to styles.xml and change theme to

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
```

**2nd Option**
if you want to toggle night mode and day mode then you can do this before setContentView(your_layout) for turning on...

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
```

and for turning off..

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
```

Comment: I am using webview in my android application. AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES does not work with webview. I need the night light feature to be activated in the device during the time when application is being used..

Comment: Can you give any app name which uses night light so that I can understand the concept of night light better.

Comment: Try this one if it answers your question https://source.android.com/devices/tech/display/night-light

Comment: Can you tell me how can I implement this doc in my code ?

Comment: I cannot find any API for this ...

Comment: No I am not familiar with night night but I found this doc. But anyways people on stack overflow will only guide you with concepts, you should implement it by your own!

Comment: Night light and night mode are two different things. The OP asks about night light and not night mode.