# Is there any way to keep theme (light /dark) active through out the app in kotlin even after you reopen the app

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Changing the theme(light/dark& default) from the dialog box using option menu.Is there any way to keep theme (light /dark) active through out the app in kotlin even after you reopen the app. I used shared preferences but unable to access that in oncreate

Comment: I think this might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/61891471/12153321 . As for saving the state, you have to save it in shared preferences.

Answer (score 0):

In your app application class :

```
override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();      
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
}
```